# Open loop PWM with SG3525

Tags: pwm, switch-mode-power-supply, inverter, converter

I have seen the same issue posted here with TL494, but The feedback pin set up in that IC, seems to be different- so that I cannot adapt it here.
[image: Block Diagram]
[image: Application]

I got an idea about how to implement a closed loop system. Vref to non inverting pin and scaled output to inverting pin.
But I need a open loop system where I can Vary the PWM duty cycle within the range using a potentiometer without taking a sample from output.
Is it possible with this chip?

Comment: Sorry something happened to post. images not legible.

Answer (score 2):

> *I need a open loop system where I can Vary the PWM duty cycle within
> the range using a potentiometer without taking a sample from output.
> Is it possible with this chip?*

Clues are in the data sheet such as this lab test fixture: -

[image]

Look bottom left and you'll see a switch that can be set to position 1 - this applies a 10 kohm feedback resistor to the error amplifier and then allows you to set the PWM output with the potentiometer shown top left.

Comment: Thanks. Basically got the  idea.
But in this method, RT is 0, that pin is grounded. it may adversely effects the existing frequency formula. Any thoughts about that?
Current formula is  Freq = 1/{( 0.7RT+3RD) * CT}

Comment: @user2454516 hmm that looks like an error. I would just assume it's an error and fit RT as per the formula.

Comment: @ Andy aka Thanks for the input. Will try out and update.

Comment: @UroBorosTech if you are done with this and have no further questions then please formally accept my answer.

Answer (score 0):

@ Andy aka Thank you very much for the information. I have tried the circuit and your assumption was correct regarding the Rt. I have wired values as per the original formula and the frequency was close to intended value. I need 25Khz PWM so need 50Khz oscillator.
[image]
In this circuit which I tried, RV1 gives control over PWM close to 50% which is maximum in this, and R17 controls frequency around 20-25Khz.
The dead time resistor which was 100 Ohms in the test set up seems to be too high considering my Ct and which resulted in considerable duty cycle loss because of high dead time. So I reduced the value to 10 Ohms here.

Thanks again!